# How to repeat grid-template-rows for all rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying create template for rows in my grid block:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px);
```

I know, this template should be work for **first 3 rows**.
However, **from 4 row** this template is not work. 
Can i make template for all rows?

P.S.
This template work only for 1st row.

```
grid-template-rows: 150px;
```

Comment: You can just set `height: 150px` on rows.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-rows` (automatically generated rows) instead of `grid-template-rows` (manually generated rows). In current case `grid-auto-rows: 150px` will do the trick. Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  /* space between columns for demo */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.grid__item {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item">One</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Two</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Three</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Four</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Five</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Six</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Seven</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Eight</div>
  <div class="grid__item">Nine</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 200px)` and `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px)` works differently? I mean `grid-template-rows` only repeats first row, but `grid-template-columns` repeats all columns.

Comment: @NanoNova Because your grid have default width of 100% of its container but default height is `auto`. Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: idk why, but it was so difficult to find this simple property (`grid-auto-rows`). Thank you! +1